# How to avoid repeating the same record in stored procedure using while?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am writing a stored procedure which will need me to calculate the time dynamically by shift.

[image]

Basically the first row are fixed, so the row after that should be able to generate itself with a simple codes like below.

Can anybody help me with this? My `while` is giving the same records. I have attach an image so that it will be easier to understand.

```
CREATE TABLE #TimeSlot
(    
         Parameter nvarchar(Max) null,
         DisplayStartTime varchar(32) not null,
         DisplayEndTime nvarchar(50)null,
         CodeEndTime nvarchar(50) null,
         Frequency int null,
         Tolerance int null
)   

INSERT INTO #TimeSlot(Parameter, DisplayStartTime, DisplayEndTime, CodeEndTime, Frequency, Tolerance)
   SELECT DISTINCT 
      Parameter, '23:00:00', 
      LTRIM((RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), DATEADD(minute, convert(int, CONVERT(int, Frequency)), '23:00:00'), 120), 8))) as DisplayEndTime
      ,LTRIM((RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), DATEADD(minute, convert(int, CONVERT(int, Frequency) + Tolerance), '23:00:00'), 120), 8))) as CodeEndTime
,Frequency,Tolerance
   FROM
      tableTest

WHILE (@intFlag <=3)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO #TimeSlot (Parameter, DisplayStartTime, DisplayEndTime, CodeEndTime, Frequency, Tolerance)
       SELECT
          Parameter, DisplayEndTime,
          LTRIM((RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), DATEADD(minute, convert(int, CONVERT(int, Frequency)), DisplayEndTime), 120), 8))) as DisplayEndTime,
          LTRIM((RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), DATEADD(minute, convert(int, CONVERT(int, Frequency) + Tolerance), DisplayEndTime), 120), 8))) as CodeEndTime,
          Frequency,
          Tolerance 
       FROM 
          #TimeSlot

    SET @intFlag = @intFlag + 1
End
```

My Expected Result:
I need something that can repeat the query without repeating the records for the DisplayStartTime, DisplayEndTime for the same Parameter.
[image]

Comment: Well if you don't do anything with the @intFlag in your SELECT part of the INSERT in the WHILE loop it is just going to repeat your query four times using the same data. This may not be the best way to do this anyway. At first glance it may be a good candidate for an APPLY query.

Comment: Do you have any suggestion for me?

Comment: what is the purpose of while here ?

Comment: i would like to loop the same query but will return different value in DisplayStartTime,DisplayEndTime,CodeEndTime. The DisplayEndTime will become my new DisplayStartTime.

Comment: Can you include your expected output?

Comment: I have added my expected results(second image)

Comment: If my boss did not expect me to work on my own projects I would be able to give you some suggestions and even some sample code. Instead of the while loop you could work with another temp table, or even beter a table variable, containing only the number 0 to 3 and then use a join or apply to create your result set.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You achieve it with the help of a CTE as a tally table, and a cross join, i did a simple one with just 3 rows, but you can search for more complete and advanced examples around SO or Google.

Try this:

```
with cte (n) as (
    select 1 UNION ALL
    select 2 UNION ALL
    select 3 
),
tableTest (
    [Parameter],
    DisplayStartTime,
    DisplayEndTime,
    CodeEndTime,
    Frequency,
    Tolerance
) as (
SELECT DISTINCT 
    Parameter, 
    '23:00:00', 
    LTRIM((RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), DATEADD(minute, convert(int, CONVERT(int, Frequency)), '23:00:00'), 120), 8))) as DisplayEndTime,
    LTRIM((RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), DATEADD(minute, convert(int, CONVERT(int, Frequency) + Tolerance), '23:00:00'), 120), 8))) as CodeEndTime,
    Frequency,
    Tolerance
FROM tableTest
)
select
    tt.[Parameter],
    DATEADD(MINUTE,Frequency*cte.n,DisplayStartTime) DisplayStartTime,
    DATEADD(MINUTE,Frequency*cte.n,DisplayEndTime) DisplayEndTime,
    DATEADD(MINUTE,(Frequency*cte.n)+ Tolerance,DisplayEndTime) CodeEndTime,
    Frequency,
    Tolerance
from tableTest tt
cross join cte
```